# Get Apache settings with corrupted httpd.conf

Tags: apache2

I writing a script, which find specific `LoadModule` directive in Apache configuration and fix path in it after software reinstall. For that I need to find where root configuration file placed. To do that I parse output of `apache2 -V` (or `httpd -V`, depend of OS). But Apache don't show this settings if configuration files is corrupted (which is why I need to fix them). Instead, it throw an error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 355 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load **** into server: ****: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Is there any way to invoke `apache2 -V` even with corrupted configuration files? Also any way to find where root configuration placed will be good.

OS: CentOS 7, Apache 2.4.6

Comment: Have you considered replacing the entire httpd.conf with your own?

Comment: @JohnMahowald That script supposed to be shipped on machines which I cannot control. Also on recent Ubuntu and Windows `apache2 -V` works even with incorrect config.